# SQL to Transform SCD stored as key value pairs into columns with history

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I have a dataset where slowly changing data is stored in the following format with key value pairs stored in rows:
The key here is the ID column. Each key has a set of attributes that is stored in the 'Dimension' column with is corresponding value (key-value pairs)
The StartDate and EndDate column provides the validity of the particular attribute. There will always be a startDate. 
EndDate - If its NULL then this is the current value of this attribute for the ID. If there is a date here then the partilar Attribute had the corresponding value in between these Start and End dates.

As in the example below, for ID-FT96, 
say on '16/01/2019' the value of attribute 'Group' was 'Group2'
'01/02/2019' the value of attribute 'Group' was 'Group22' but as of today the Group is 'Group2'.
Where the EndDate is NULL, that suggests the attribute values as of the current day.

```
  StartDate  |  EndDate   |   ID   | Dimension |    Value    
 ------------|------------|--------|-----------|------------- 
  02/11/2018 | 19/11/2018 | FTID15 | Name      | Name1       
  02/11/2018 | NULL       | FTID15 | Status    | Active      
  02/11/2018 | NULL       | FTID15 | Group     | Group1      
  02/11/2018 | NULL       | FTID15 | Sub Group | SUB Group1  
  20/11/2018 | 19/12/2018 | FTID15 | Name      | Name2       
  20/12/2018 | 23/01/2019 | FTID15 | Name      | Name3       
  24/01/2019 | 20/02/2019 | FTID15 | Name      | Name4       
  21/02/2019 | 27/02/2019 | FTID15 | Name      | Name5       
  28/02/2019 | NULL       | FTID15 | Sub Group | SUB Group2  
  02/11/2018 | 19/11/2018 | FTID12 | Name      | Namex1      
  02/11/2018 | NULL       | FTID12 | Status    | Active      
  02/11/2018 | NULL       | FTID12 | Group     | Group2      
  02/11/2018 | NULL       | FTID12 | Sub Group | SUB Group13 
  20/11/2018 | NULL       | FTID12 | Name      | Namex2      
  02/11/2018 | NULL       | FT96   | Name      | NameYY      
  02/11/2018 | NULL       | FT96   | Status    | Active      
  02/11/2018 | 27/01/2019 | FT96   | Group     | Group2      
  02/11/2018 | 27/01/2019 | FT96   | Sub Group | SUB Group1  
  28/01/2019 | 05/02/2019 | FT96   | Group     | Group22     
  28/01/2019 | NULL       | FT96   | Sub Group | SUB Group22 
  06/02/2019 | 11/02/2019 | FT96   | Group     | Group1      
  12/02/2019 | NULL       | FT96   | Group     | Group2
```

I need some help to transform this data in SQL to be stored in the following format. 
Here, the resultant dataset should have each 'Dimension' as an individual column with its corresponding value as the values for the column.
It should have a row for every change in the any of the dimension values giving a snapshot of values of all dimensions between updates in a single row.

The resultant output should look like the following.

```
  StartDate  |  EndDate   |   ID   |  Name  | Status |  Group  |  Sub Group  
 ------------|------------|--------|--------|--------|---------|------------- 
  02/11/2018 | 19/11/2018 | FTID15 | Name1  | Active | Group1  | SUB Group1  
  20/11/2018 | 19/12/2018 | FTID15 | Name2  | Active | Group1  | SUB Group1  
  20/12/2018 | 23/01/2019 | FTID15 | Name3  | Active | Group1  | SUB Group1  
  24/01/2019 | 20/02/2019 | FTID15 | Name4  | Active | Group1  | SUB Group1  
  21/02/2019 | 27/02/2019 | FTID15 | Name5  | Active | Group1  | SUB Group1  
  28/02/2019 | NULL       | FTID15 | Name5  | Active | Group1  | SUB Group2  
  02/11/2018 | 19/11/2018 | FTID12 | Namex1 | Active | Group2  | SUB Group13 
  20/11/2018 | NULL       | FTID12 | Namex2 | Active | Group2  | SUB Group13 
  2018-11-02 | 2019-01-27 | FT96   | NameYY | Active | Group2  | SUB Group1  
  2019-01-28 | 2019-02-05 | FT96   | NameYY | Active | Group22 | SUB Group22 
  2019-02-06 | 2019-02-11 | FT96   | NameYY | Active | Group1  | SUB Group22 
  2019-02-12 | NULL       | FT96   | NameYY | Active | Group2  | SUB Group22
```

Here the dimension value are not just limited to the 4 mentioned in the example. This can vary and needs to be transformed automatically irrespective of the number of dimensions.

Comment: Please explain the logic for the transformation and add a tag for the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. PIVOT and some window functions can solve your problem.

```
SELECT 
 StartDate,
 EndDate,
 ID,
 ISNULL([Name], FIRST_VALUE([Name]) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY StartDate))  AS [Name], 
 ISNULL([Status], FIRST_VALUE([Status]) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY StartDate))  AS [Status], 
 ISNULL([Group], FIRST_VALUE([Group]) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY StartDate))   AS [Group], 
 ISNULL([Sub Group], FIRST_VALUE([Sub Group]) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY StartDate))AS [Sub Group]
FROM (
    SELECT StartDate, 
        ISNULL(EndDate,  MAX(EndDate) OVER(PARTITION BY StartDate,ID )) AS EndDate,
        ID, Dimension, Value 
    FROM MyTable
) SRC
PIVOT(MAX( Value) FOR Dimension IN ([Name], [Status], [Group], [Sub Group])) PVT
order by ID desc, StartDate
```

Dynamic version:

```
DECLARE @Columns NVARCHAR(MAX) =''
DECLARE @PivotIn NVARCHAR(MAX) =''

SELECT 
  @PivotIn = CONCAT(@PivotIn ,', ', QUOTENAME(Dimension))
, @Columns = CONCAT(@Columns , ', ', 'ISNULL(',QUOTENAME(Dimension),', FIRST_VALUE(',QUOTENAME(Dimension),') OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY StartDate))  AS ',QUOTENAME(Dimension),'')
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT Dimension FROM MyTable   ) AS X

DECLARE @SqlQuery NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT 
    StartDate,
    EndDate,
    ID ' + 
    @Columns 
    +' FROM 
    (
        SELECT StartDate, 
            ISNULL(EndDate,  MAX(EndDate) OVER(PARTITION BY StartDate,ID )) AS EndDate,
            ID, Dimension, Value 
        FROM MyTable

    ) SRC
    PIVOT(MAX( Value) FOR Dimension IN (' +  STUFF(@PivotIn,1,1,'') + ')) PVT
    ORDER BY ID DESC, StartDate'


EXEC sp_executesql @SqlQuery
```

Comment: Thanks @Serkan-Arslan. The only issue here is that the dimensions can be dynamic where new ones can be introduced. With this query the dimension columns will be hard coded and with any change in the dimension value the query will need to be updated. To make it dynamic may need to use dynamic sql?

Comment: I added dynamic version of it.

Comment: Hi @serkan-arslan, 

When input is :

SStartDate|EndDate|ID|Dimension|Value
31/10/2018||7|D1|V1
31/10/2018||7|D2|V2
31/10/2018|17/03/2019|7|D3|V3
31/10/2018||7|D4|V2
27/01/2019||7|D25|V18
27/01/2019||7|D26|V18
18/03/2019||7|D3|V4

query o/p is incorrect:

startdate|enddate|id|D1|D2|D3|D4|D25|D26
2018-10-31|2019-03-17|7|V1|V2|V3|V2||
2019-01-27||7|V1|V2|V3|V2|V18|V18
2019-03-18||7|V1|V2|V4|V2||

o/p expected:

startdate|enddate|id|D1|D2|D3|D4|D25|D26
2018-10-31|2019-01-26|7|V1|V2|V3|V2||
2019-01-27|2019-03-17|7|V1|V2|V3|V2|V18|V18
2019-03-18||7|V1|V2|V4|V2|V2|V18|V18

Comment: If a new dimension is added for an ID at a later stage then the output of query seems to show an additional row with just the value for this new dimension populated and value of the other dimensions as null.Basically when a new dimension is added then a new row with start date and end date as null/blank should be added will all existing dimension values as well as the new one added.And existing rows end date should be set.The eg I provided in the comment earlier illustrates this issue.Trust this helps understand the logic.There should only be one row for an Id with the end date as null/blank.

Comment: can you change `over` part of this line `ISNULL(EndDate,  MAX(EndDate) OVER(PARTITION BY StartDate,ID )) AS EndDate` to `OVER(PARTITION BY ID )` and try again?